# Office 365 rest API to create a user account

Tags: rest, api, office365

I want to implement user account creation through Office 365 REST APIs. I can't find it in any documentation. Can anyone please guide me.

The use case is that I have a company account and when people are hired, I would like to invoke the REST API and create an account for the new joinees.

Comment: Hi, did you find how to do it?